# Sharepoint 2010 list view threshold and item level permissions

Tags: sharepoint

I am building up a list that each list item will have certain permission groups applied by a workflow.

Other than the admin group which is applied to every item, it will be virtually impossible for any one group to have more records in any fiscal year that will exceed the list view threshold.

If a fiscal year list view filter webpart is provided will the view quantity stay below the threshold because of the item level permissions?

Indexes are set on Fiscal Year, Item Code, Department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threshold is on the original view and not on the filters applied to the view after the fact.  The search web parts aren't affected by the threshold.  That may be an alternative option for you.

Also, you may want to revisit your design if you can.  You may eventually experience performance issues with all of those unique permissions.

Comment: I am not looking at the search web part I am looking at the List Filter web part.  Also, I understand the item level permissions is not a good business practice but due to lack of standardization in the user information list it's difficult for me to see a scheme I can use to keep on department from see another department's data and keep it all in one place. I need to get this locked down before the former list goes over 5,000 items.